# Is it possible to get a transit visa for UK within a few hours?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

My friend is currently on a flight from Dresden to Zurich, and will have a 6 hour layover till he gets on a flight from Zurich to London. He was just told in Dresden that he would require a Transit Visa when he lands in London, where he has a layover of 3 hours, without which he won't be permitted to board the flight to New Delhi.

Is it possible for him to obtain a Transit Visa for Heathrow while waiting in Zurich?

What are the options that he could consider here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to be clear, without the UK transit visa, your friend will not be allowed to board the Zurich to London flight. His options, therefore, are only one: to change his itinerary so as to not pass through the UK.

There is no reasonable way to obtain a UK visa within "hours". It requires filing a visa application and sending out your passport and paperwork to a consulate and waiting several days.

In some countries there is a super priority visa service which can return a UK visa decision within 24 hours; it can cost between £500-£1000 depending on country. But this isn't going to happen within the time of a flight layover, and it will probably cost as much or less to change the flight itinerary anyway.

He's already in Schengen; there are flights to India from a variety of European airports in the Schengen area that either fly direct or transit via somewhere reasonable like UAE. There are many, many options. If he's flying on Jet Airways/Swissair they should be able to re-route him through AMS, i.e. ZRH-AMS-DEL. Even throwing away the entire ticket and booking something new might be an option; I see a last minute ZRH-SVO-DEL on 
Aeroflot for CHF357 one way.

Comment: SVO doesn't need a transit visa, I hope?

Comment: @AnirudThyagharajan [You don't need a transit visa at SVO if you remain airside.](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=IN&DE=IN&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=RU&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX)

Comment: This helped a lot!